# ¿Qué significa ../ a la hora de importar en TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Sucede que estoy aprendiendo TypeScript y en la parte superior de los archivos .ts los módulos importados después del from llevan dos puntos seguidos de slash 
" ../ " y no sé que significa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Son los niveles de tus carpetas empezando desde los archivos que estan en la misma carpeta.

```
import Nivel from './mismoNivel'
import Nivel from '../padre/mismoNivel'
import Nivel from '../../proyecto/padre/mismoNivel'
```

Hay una opción para evitar esto modificando tu `tsconfig.json` de esta manera.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react",
        // Esta es la basee
        "baseUrl": "src",
        //Estas son las rutas que defines.
        "paths": {
            "actions/*": [ "app/actions/*" ],
            "selectors/*": [ "app/selectors/*" ],
            "ui/*": [ "app/ui/*" ],
            "logger": [ "util/logger" ],
        }
    }
}
```

La información la saque de [aqui](https://decembersoft.com/posts/say-goodbye-to-relative-paths-in-typescript-imports/).